# Auto sync Sharepoint document library with Dropbox

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I'm looking for module or 3rd-party integration which can do sync between SharePoint Document Library (under Office365) and Dropbox folder? 
Basically, our clients are using Dropbox (and they share that with us via Dropbox) and we want to auto upload their Dropbox changes into our SharePoint Library.

The updates also need to be uploaded (i.e., if our partner updates the file) and we need to track owners of files.

Answer (score 3):

One good solution for this is cloudHQ: https://www.cloudHQ.net/sync/office365_sharepoint/dropbox - it easy setup and you can sync with multiple Dropbox accounts. You can also setup one-way or two-way sync. You can also chose automatic archiving of changes (as backup).

With cloudHQ, you get the following:

- Real-time sync
- One-way or two-way sync (i.e., pick up only changes from Dropbox and put them in SharePoint, or sync them so that folder in SharePoint and Dropbox are exact copies of each other)
- Replication of ownership info (i.e., if user X uploads file in Dropbox and that user exists in SharePoint that will be owner of that files in sharePoint)
- Sync multiple Dropbox accounts

As far as I understand spdockit.com will only upload changes from Dropbox so that might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

I dont use this but I tested it a couple of months ago and worked fine.

http://www.spdockit.com/support/help/how-to/synchronization/sync-to-dropbox/